# getting filtered array from array with condition php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This codes are with Codeigniter framework,

I have below array $csv_array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [location] => X33 [usernumber] => 1 [order] => XX [part_number] => Hi ) [1] => Array ( [location] => X33 [usernumber] => 1 [order] => XX [part_number] => 68730 ) [2] => Array ( [location] => W33 [usernumber] => 2 [order] => YY [part_number] => 68741) [3] => Array ( [location] => W33 [usernumber] => 2 [order] => YY [part_number] => Hello )
```

My requirements,

create an array for each usernumber(here 2 different user) which contains location, part_number, order and then send email only 2 times, 1 to each user with information of array generated for usernumber,

I tried below step code but i lost in loops!

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row)
            {
                $user = $this->admin_model->get_usershipment($row['usernumber']);
                $order_data = array();

                for ($i=0; $i < count($csv_array); $i++)
                {
                    if($row['usernumber'] == $user->usernumber)
                    {
                        //Create some array to send????
                        $order_data = array();

                       //Should be something like below, but should contain for usernumber 1 only, and then in 2nd email it should be for usernumber 2 only
                        //$order_data = array('location' => $row['location'], 'part_number' => $row['part_number'], 'order' => $row['order']);
                    }
                }

                $data = array(
                    'user_firstname'    =>  $user->user_firstname,
                    'user_email'        =>  $user->user_email,
                   'order_data' => $order_data);

                $subject = 'Hello Update! ';
                $message = $this->parser->parse('templates/notification', $data, TRUE);

                $this->emailnotification($user->user_email, $subject, $message);
            }
```

One more problem here is that emailnotification fuction will run 4 times, which i want only for 2 time, means to 2 users only,

Any guide how i can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There can be many approaches if i understand you correctly. One solution can be (This is just demo use your own sense to modify it):-

```
foreach($csv_array as $row)
{
    $csv_array1[$row['usernumber']][] = $row
}
foreach ($csv_array1 as $key=>$details)
{

    $user = $this->admin_model->get_usershipment($key);
    $data = array(
            'user_firstname'    =>  $user->user_firstname,
            'user_email'        =>  $user->user_email,
           'order_data' => $details);//$details has 2 arrays for each user 
    $subject = 'Hello Update! ';
    $message = $this->parser->parse('templates/notification', $data, TRUE);
    $this->emailnotification($user->user_email, $subject, $message);
}
```

Comment: Yes, i think this will help to send email if it not sent earlier in loop, but how can i create filtered array for specific usernumber? here its $order_data

Comment: And For each user there is 2 orders which order you want to send as notification ??

Comment: i had added note in code, from whole array it should filter for usernumber 1 only and then send email, same thing for usernumber 2

Comment: almost there, but how you added location, part_number, order in $details array?

Comment: i got my answer and resolved! Thanks for ur help for email notification

Comment: @rjcode i am glad i could be some help.. mark my answer if it suits your need :)